# Why is no result in this code?

Tags: python

emp.csv

```
  index   empno   ename   job        mgr      hiredate    sal comm    deptno
      0,  7839,   KING,   PRESIDENT,  0,      1981-11-17, 5000,   0,  10
      1,  7698,   BLAKE,  MANAGER,    7839,   1981-05-01, 2850,   0,  30
      2,  7782,   CLARK,  MANAGER,    7839,   1981-05-09, 2450,   0,  10
      3,  7566,   JONES,  MANAGER,    7839,   1981-04-01, 2975,   0,  20
      4,  7654,   MARTIN, SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-09-10, 1250,   1400,   30
      5,  7499,   ALLEN,  SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-02-11, 1600    300,    30
      6,  7844,   TURNER, SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-08-21, 1500,   0,  30
      7,  7900,   JAMES,  CLERK,      7698,   1981-12-11, 950,    0,  30
      8,  7521,   WARD,   SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-02-23, 1250,   500,    30
      9,  7902,   FORD,   ANALYST,    7566,   1981-12-11, 3000,   0,  20
      10, 7369,   SMITH,  CLERK,      7902,   1980-12-09, 800,    0,  20
      11, 7788,   SCOTT,  ANALYST,    7566    1982-12-22, 3000,   0,  20
      12, 7876,   ADAMS,  CLERK,      7788,   1983-01-15, 1100,   0,  20
      13, 7934,   MILLER, CLERK,      7782,   1982-01-11, 1300,   0,  10
```

I can get to below result in this code.

```
import csv

job = input('Enter the job : ' )

with open("D:\R data\emp2.csv", 'r') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
     for row in reader:
          if all(s in job for s in row[2]):
              print (row[1],row[5],row[2])
```

result :

```
Enter the job : SALESMAN,ANALYST
MARTIN 1250 SALESMAN
ALLEN 1600 SALESMAN
TURNER 1500 SALESMAN
WARD 1250 SALESMAN
FORD 3000 ANALYST
SCOTT 3000 ANALYST
```

But I can't get to above result in below code. No result.

I want to change  "job = 'SALESMAN','ANALYST' "  of below code.

```
import csv

job = 'SALESMAN','ANALYST'

with open("D:\R data\emp2.csv", 'r') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
     for row in reader:
          if all(s in job for s in row[2]):
              print (row[1],row[5],row[2])
```

How can I get to below result in above code ?

```
MARTIN 1250 SALESMAN
ALLEN 1600 SALESMAN
TURNER 1500 SALESMAN
WARD 1250 SALESMAN
FORD 3000 ANALYST
SCOTT 3000 ANALYST
```

Comment: change `job` into a list containing the terms like so: `job = ['SALESMAN', 'ANALYST']`. Make sure that `s` does not contain the delimiter (',' in this case).

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Job` has to be some kind of container to be used with the `in` keyword. That does not mean that you cannot have it with **user input**. For example you can do this:

```
keywords = input('Provide the search strings separated by commas (','):\t').split(',')
```

Furthermore, the csv file you are reading contains slashes in its path. Slashes are used as escape characters in strings so the file is not read at all in your case since the path throws an error. Use this `with open(r"D:\R data\emp2.csv", 'r') as f:` instead. notice the `r` in front of the string. This tells python to read it as it is, disregarding escapes. Alternativelly, you can use double slashes (thus actually escaping the slashes themselves) like: `with open("D:\\R data\\emp2.csv", 'r') as f:`.

Additionally, the indexes you use are wrong. **Python uses zero index!** So you have to check `row[3]` for the keywords and return `row[2], row[6], row[3]` based on the desired output, not check row[2] and return 1,5 & 2.

Finally, your check is wrong. What you want to see is if `row[3]` is any off the strings you supplied. You can simply do this by `if row[3] in job:`

Putting everything together we have:

```
import csv

job = input('Provide the search strings separated by commas (','):\t').split(',')

with open(r"C:\Users\evkouni\Desktop\test.csv", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if row[3] in job:
            print(row[2], row[6], row[3])
```

**DEMO:**

Runing the above with the provided *.csv file (you were also missing some commas) returns:

```
#MARTIN 1250 SALESMAN
#ALLEN 1600 SALESMAN
#TURNER 1500 SALESMAN
#WARD 1250 SALESMAN
#FORD 3000 ANALYST
#SCOTT 3000 ANALYST
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  thank to your answer , I was able to get to result that i want.

Comment: @yuyeonsu Fish are temporary, fishing is what counts. Is there anything about the answer that is not clear to you?

Comment: I am glad to your advice.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

- The input of the user has to be broken into individual tokens, this can be done with `job = input('Enter the job : ').split(",")`
- the statement `if all(s in job for s in row[2])` looks weird to me. You check whether every character of column 2 is contained in your job string. I think you would want to do `if row[3].strip() in job:` The `strip` is necessary because the csv input contains leading slashes.